# Multiple Definition even with Include Guards

Tags: c++

I've hit my first assignment requiring object oriented programs. I started working on the (rather large and complicated) project and hit a few snags when it came to linking multiple class files and their associated .h files. Basically I keep getting "Multiple Definition of Class" errors, even though I have my Include guards and theres no Global Variables. I won't post my code for the assignment itself, but here's a much simplified example giving me an identical error:

```
//Runner file.
#include "Class1.cpp"
int main(){
    Class1 classtest();
    return 0;
}
```

-

```
//Class1.h
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H
class Class1
{
    public:
        Class1();
};
#endif // CLASS1_H
```

-

```
//Class1.cpp
#include "Class1.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Class2.cpp"
using namespace std;
Class1::Class1()
{ 
    cout << "Created Test Class1";
    Class2 testClass();
}
```

And then nearly identical Class2 files

```
//Class2.h
#ifndef CLASS2_H
#define CLASS2_H
class Class2
{
    public:
        Class2();
};
#endif // CLASS2_H
```

-

```
#include "Class2.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Class2::Class2()
{
    cout << "Created Class 2";
}
```

The whole thing then generates around 1.4 metric craptons of errors, most of which are in the format:
`obj\Debug\Runner.o||In function`Class2':|C:\Users\MikeD\Desktop\C++\ObjectOTesting\Class2.cpp|6|
    multiple definition of`Class2::Class2()'|
obj\Debug\Class2.o:C:\Users\MikeD\Desktop\C++\ObjectOTesting\Class2.cpp|6|first defined here|`

I KNOW I'm doing something stupid here, but I haven't been able to find out what exactly. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't include cpp files.

Comment: Then what alternative is there?

Comment: @MikeDaoust: To include only the header... let the linker do its job.

Comment: @MikeDaoust, Do you use an IDE? If so, which one?

Comment: @MikeDaoust - You'll need to compile all three program files separately, and then link together the resulting object file. If you tell us what compiler and/or IDE you are using, someone will probably give you instructions on how to do that.

Comment: You include the .h files as necessary and then compile all the .cpp files.

Comment: Ah, I guess you do. IDEs generally link things automatically for you when using projects.

Comment: To specify, Chris and Rob's solution of changing the .cpp includes to .h files fixed everything. Such a little thing to pull so much hair out over. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't `#include` CPP files -- you compile them.  CPP files, in turn, `#include` H files.